# Prometheus Adapter - Problem with Custom Metrics ( FailedDiscoveryCheck)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubectl, prometheus-adapter

In my project, I am trying to implement custom metrics to support HPA in K8S.

With this guide [Prometheus Custom Metrics Adapter](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.0-v2.4/explanations/integrations-in-rancher/cluster-monitoring/custom-metrics#configuration-of-prometheus-custom-metrics-adapter) step by step I prepare code and implement into my cluster *(only different is that in my version of k8s I'm using v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io not v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io)*

I'm using GKE in GCP.

YAML file with pods and services:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: fb-poster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - '--storage.tsdb.retention=6h'
            - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: data-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-config
        - name: data-volume
          emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-adapter-monitor
  labels:
    app: prometheus-adapter-monitor
  namespace: fb-poster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-adapter-monitor
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-adapter-monitor
      name: prometheus-adapter-monitor
    spec:

      serviceAccountName: cluster-monitoring
      containers:
        - name: prometheus-adapter-monitor
          image: directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter-amd64:v0.5.0
          args:
            - "--secure-port=6443"
            - "--tls-cert-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.crt"
            - "--tls-private-key-file=/var/run/serving-cert/serving.key"
            - "--logtostderr=true"
            - "--metrics-relist-interval=1m"
            - "--prometheus-url=http://prometheus-service:9090"
            - "--v=10"
            - "--config=etc/adapter/config.yml"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6443
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/serving-cert
              name: volume-serving-cert
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /etc/adapter/
              name: config
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: tmp-vol
      volumes:
        - name: volume-serving-cert
          secret:
            secretName: cm-adapter-serving-certs
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-config
        - name: tmp-vol
          emptyDir: {}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-adapter-monitor
  namespace: fb-poster
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 6443
  selector:
    app: prometheus-adapter-monitor
---
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  service:
    name: prometheus-adapter-monitor
    namespace: fb-poster
  group: custom.metrics.k8s.io
  version: v1
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  versionPriority: 100
```

configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-config
  namespace: fb-poster
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval: 10s
      evaluation_interval: 10s
    
    rule_files:
    - "custom_rules.yml"

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'selenium-hub'
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['selenium-hub-export-service:9104']

      - job_name: 'prometheus'
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['prometheus-service:9090']

  custom_rules.yml: |
    groups:
      - name: custom.rules
        rules:
          - record: free_nodes_percentage
            expr: 100 * (selenium_grid_node_count - selenium_grid_session_count) / selenium_grid_node_count

  config.yml: |
    rules:
      - seriesQuery: 'free_nodes_percentage'
        resources:
          overrides:
            kubernetes_namespace: {resource: "namespace"}
            kubernetes_pod_name: {resource: "pod"}
        name:
          matches: "free_nodes_percentage"
```

After applying this YAML to the cluster, all my pods are working. from the prometheus-adapter-monitor pod, I get the logs:

```
I0620 21:06:01.122341       1 api.go:74] GET http://prometheus-service:9090/api/v1/series?match%5B%5D=selenium_grid_node_count%7Bkubernetes_namespace%21%3D%22%22%2Ckubernetes_pod_name%21%3D%22%22%7D&start=1687293961.117 200 OK      
I0620 21:06:01.122618       1 api.go:93] Response Body: {"status":"success","data":[]}
I0620 21:06:01.122800       1 provider.go:270] Set available metric list from Prometheus to: [[]]
I0620 21:06:01.286377       1 handler.go:143] prometheus-metrics-adapter: GET "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1" satisfied by gorestful with webservice /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io
I0620 21:06:01.286709       1 wrap.go:42] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1: (736.267µs) 404 [[Go-http-client/2.0] 10.45.0.31:48374]
```

When i `kubectl describe apiservice v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io` i recived:

```
Name:         v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
Namespace:
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         APIService
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-06-20T21:04:55Z
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        f:group:
        f:groupPriorityMinimum:
        f:insecureSkipTLSVerify:
        f:service:
          .:
          f:name:
          f:namespace:
          f:port:
        f:version:
        f:versionPriority:
    Manager:      kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-06-20T21:04:55Z
    API Version:  apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
          .:
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .:
            f:lastTransitionTime:
            f:message:
            f:reason:
            f:status:
            f:type:
    Manager:         kube-apiserver
    Operation:       Update
    Subresource:     status
    Time:            2023-06-20T21:05:02Z
  Resource Version:  11540103
  UID:               7c82cbb9-41df-4469-9394-a03da9d34bef
Spec:
  Group:                     custom.metrics.k8s.io
  Group Priority Minimum:    100
  Insecure Skip TLS Verify:  true
  Service:
    Name:            prometheus-adapter-monitor
    Namespace:       fb-poster
    Port:            443
  Version:           v1
  Version Priority:  100
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-06-20T21:04:55Z
    Message:               failing or missing response from https://10.45.1.70:6443/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1: bad status from https://10.45.1.70:6443/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1: 404
    Reason:                FailedDiscoveryCheck
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Available
Events:                    <none>
```

I have no clue how can i solve this problem. I found some related posts, but they don't cover my problem and are from a few years ago.

---

UPDATE 27.06.2023
@DanF according to your answer I have checked my cluster network details:

```
Private cluster Disabled        
Network default     
Subnet  default     
Stack type  IPv4        
Private control plane’s endpoint subnet default     
VPC-native traffic routing  Enabled     
Pod IPv4 address range (default)    10.82.128.0/17      
Cluster Pod IPv4 ranges (additional)    None        
IPv4 service range  10.83.0.0/22
```

so I have filled @DanF commend like:
`gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-prometheus-adapter --action ALLOW --direction INGRESS --source-ranges 110.82.128.0/17 --rules tcp:6443 --network default`

but still I'm reciving same error:

```
Spec:
  Group:                     custom.metrics.k8s.io
  Group Priority Minimum:    100
  Insecure Skip TLS Verify:  true
  Service:
    Name:            prometheus-adapter-monitor
    Namespace:       fb-poster
    Port:            443
  Version:           v1
  Version Priority:  100
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-06-27T19:07:53Z
    Message:               failing or missing response from https://10.82.128.155:6443/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1: bad status from https://10.82.128.155:6443/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1: 404
    Reason:                FailedDiscoveryCheck
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Available
Events:                    <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I ran into this a while ago, not sure if it's the same issue but my solution was to run

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-prometheus-adapter \
    --action ALLOW \
    --direction INGRESS \
    --source-ranges 10.0.0.0/8 \ # Master CIDR Block Change it to fit your K8s Cluster
    --rules tcp:6443 \
    --network {{VPC Network Name}} # Get this from the UI Console
```

I think the main cause is that you are not allowing traffic into that port and failing the discovery check.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: @Danf I updated my post with action I took according to your post. Still have problem.

Comment: The source range is wrong no? 110.82.128.0/17 should be 10.82.128.0/17? I dont see any ip starting with 110.x.x.x so I may need more context here.

Comment: @DanF Sorry I've made a typo above. As you wrote, I used 10.82.128.0/17 source range. Problem still is the same. What context do I need to provide for you?